# How to access audio file from document directory?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have an audio file stored in document directory, and now I need to get that audio file and do some encryption/Decryption. 
I want exactly like this:

```
let audiofile = get audio file from document directory // This is what i want

encrypt(audiofile)// I have AES technique, This is not my question.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple!!!!

Just Code like Below ::

```
var paths: [AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

let audiofilePath = paths[0].stringByAppendingString("/myaudio.mp3")

//Write name of your audio at **myaudio.mp3**

//now you can use anywhere audiofilePath as String like

let audiourl : NSURL = NSURL((fileURLWithPath: audiofilePath))

//or you can make asset like

let assets = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audiofilePath))
```

Enjoy Coding and if any help need just ask me..

Comment: in audiourl it just file path right? where should be audio file? assets?

Comment: What if i play asset through avaudioplayer? will it play?

Comment: If you want to play.. You can do...  self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audiofilePath))

Comment: Inboth with asset and url you can play audio.. But the condition is the audio must exist at that path..

Comment: contact me on gmail chat aiyub.pixster@gmail.com

Comment: thanks. it worked : NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audiofilePath))

Comment: @JAck how I can save audio file to documents directory

Comment: Great! Thank you!